# Theorem plus_n_n_injective, exercise

Tags: coq

Help needed with an exercise from [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/). This is the theorem:

```
Theorem plus_n_n_injective : ∀n m,
 n + n = m + m →
 n = m.
Proof.
```

I end up with `n = 0` as goal and `n + n = 0` as hypothesis. How to move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect `n` (`destruct` it), it's either going to be `0` in which case the goal is provable by reflexivity, or `S n'` in which case the hypothesis is contradictory by `congruence`/`inversion`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the `destruct` and `inversion` tactic?

Comment: `destruct n.` does case analysis on `n`, exposing one case for each constructor of `n`'s type. `inversion` does case analysis while preserving facts about `n`'s indices. You should be able to learn about them in any decent Coq introduction. For instance, this chapter of CPDT covers `inversion`: http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Predicates.html

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I'm stuck at another place, with goal `n + n = m + m` and hypothesis `S n + S n = S m + S m`. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: -1 How is 0 = m provable by reflexivity? Also, book suggests proving by induction on n not destruct. This is rather misleading and leaves the @OlleHärstedt somewhat worse of.

Answer (score 3):

`n + n` cannot be simplified further because `n` is a variable, not a type constructor.
You can expose all the construction cases of `n` by `destruct`ing it as Ptival said. However using `inversion` in this context seems to me a bit extreme and not what this Sf exercise is about.

When replaced by the `O` constructor, `O + O` will reduce (using `simpl` for example) to `O` and `reflexivity` should do the trick.

When replaced by the `S` constructor, `S foo + bar` will always reduce to the shape `S something`, which can't be equal to `O` (the easiest way to assert that is by using `discriminate`) because they are two constructors of the same type.

Best,
V.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to solving this problem can be garnered from the Theorem for length_snoc' previously shown in the same chapter.

As this was the first time so far in the book that introducing some of the variable/hypothesis after doing an induction on n, this may come off as unusual to newcomers (like me). This allows you to get a more general hypotheses in your context after proving for the base case.

As mentioned before, you will be able to prove some goals simply by reflexivity. Some of them can be proven by inversion on a false hypotheses in your context(those should become straightforward once you spot them, the idea that `2 + 2 = 5 -> anything` is true can go a long way).

Finally, you will have to rework one of your hypotheses using the previously defined lemmas plus_n_Sm and eq_add_S as well as symmetry to be able to apply the more general hypotheses we discussed earlier.

Comment: At least in the current version, there is no `length_snoc'` theorem in the whole book :(